# does Jaeger provide a trace api

Tags: api, zipkin, opentracing, jaeger

does jaeger provide a way of querying the trace data without using the UI provided. I'm aware that zipkin provides an API to directly access the trace data etc. 
Use-case: i'm trying to use the trace data to pull together a custom report for internal purposes. I could scrape the data from the UI but wondered if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best chance is to get the data from whatever storage the Jaeger collector is using (Cassandra, Elastic.) (https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.6/deployment/ )

My suggestion is to store in Elastic and use Kibana to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but the current version of Jaeger Query UI is a single page app and has an underlying API that allows the same queries capabilities as the UI.

Comment: unfortunately,  the API document section explicitly warns that the HTTP query API "is intentionally undocumented".